# php CodeIgniter error uri

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently I have create a website using codeigniter.
I got a message error every times i do request to the url which have some special character.
The example about url below is the sample of error

http://localhost/project/index.php?admin/phone_edit/150/SII(16GB)

An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your config.php file there's a setting of allowed characters. add ( and ) in the list.